# When should you start treating a quadratic as a linear in numerical root-finding?

Tags: numerical-methods, quadratic

I have a set of quadratic coefficients a, b, and c the need to be solved in order to determine the intersection between two graphs on a plane (lets say, a parabola and a line).

My problem, however, is that when my parabola is so "stretched out" that it starts behaving like a line around the area of interest, it seems like disregarding the a coefficient and instead solving linearly for b and c works perfectly.

My question is, at what point do you decide the solve the quadratic linearly? By extension, when should you solve a cubic equation quadratically?

Of course there are actually 2 roots on the quadratic, but (from the computer's perspective and for all intense and purposes) there is only 1 root.

Edit:

I've added a lot more detail to this question on the maths stack exchange, but I still feel that because this has to do with numerical instability, I should ask here. Here is the maths question which was phrased slightly different: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000135/quadratic-formula-fails-numerically-at-small-a-coefficients

Comment: This looks like a question for [maths.se].As it stands, there's no obvious programming content here. I suspect that the answer lies in the acceptable margin of error, but only you could decide that.

Comment: Thanks @TangentiallyPerpendicular I thought maybe because it fell into the relm of numerical instability that I should ask it here, but I'll cross post it there and see how things go

Comment: (It is "intents and purposes", or perhaps "intense purposes"). This kind of contemplation is the basis for all numerical root finding method. One cuts the Taylor expansion at the linear or quadratic term and uses the known solution formulas to find the next root approximation. See Newton's method and Halley's method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem is more common than I thought. Relevant answers have been posted in the maths thread I linked, but you can also checked out this one page paper which is rather straight forward. https://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Quadratics.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It was Newton's idea to expand around a guess `x` for a root of a cubic equation

```
0 = (x+h)^3 + a*(x+h)^2 + b*(x+h) + c
  = x^2+a*x^2+b*x+c + (3*x^2+2*a*x+b)*h + ...
```

and take the constant and linear terms to determine an improvement `h` for the root (in this generality the method was formulated only some decades later by Raphson and Simpson).

Halley in the computation of the comet named after him had the idea to take also the quadratic term of the Taylor expansion and use the quadratic solution formula. Switching around the Taylor expansion of the square root or the division results in the modern Halley method, Laguerre's method and (Euler-)Chebyshev method, all of third order. In formulas with multiple solutions, the one giving the smallest `h` is chosen.